# how do i write select query based on current time?

Tags: php, mysql

how do i select users on based on current system time? i have two columns in mysql database logintime and logout time both are getting system or current time when user logintime or logout timebut i want select user based on logintime or logout time ?? If queries fetch row from mysql database then it should be display username when user login or logout?

```
 $query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOW() 
 ORDER BY logouttime DESC LIMIT 2")  or die ("users query2");
 $row2=mysql_fetch_array($query2);

 if($query){
 ?> 
 Username: <?php echo $row['username'] ?>

 <?php } else if($query2){?>
 Username: <?php echo $row['username'] ?>
 <?php }?>
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't just append question marks to declarative statements, but rather ask real questions. What exactly do you mean by "select user based on login time"?

Comment: i want to select user through logintime?

Comment: Let's assume it's April 4, 05:20 now. Which users do you want to select?

Comment: You want to pass a certain time to your query and get all users that were online at that time?

Comment: let's assume zamzama is login and time is 05:19:19 and it should be display zamazama details

Comment: only zamazama? Not administrator?

Comment: How is this supposed to work if the login and logout are on different days?

Comment: I don't get something. How can the current time be between logintime and logouttime? That means that logouttime is in the future!

Answer (score 1):

This should give the desired outcome:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE `date`=DATE(NOW()) AND TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN logintime AND logouttime
```

It would be better to make the `logintime` and `logouttime` of the type `DATETIME`, in which case you can simply do:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN logintime AND logouttime
```

Comment: I hope so... That would also include "Administrator" for 05:19:19.

Comment: @MartyMcVry Yep, that's right.

Comment: What happens if they login before midnight and logout after midnight?

Comment: @Barmar Good point, added a recommendation :) thanks!

Comment: @Barmar u r right because it should be include am or pm system ?

Comment: @FarhanAziz No, the login and logout time should include the date; what if they log out only after two days?

Comment: @jack atuallly this is web based office or business management system so administrator wants to be monitor all users when they are login or logout from the system?